# Azure DevOps Project Attachment

Tags: azure-devops-server-2020

I did a trial run on migrating a 2015 TFS projection collection to 2020 DevOps.  It went successfully but now I have to redo the migration since some time has past and the developers have updated the 2015 TFS project collection.  I redid my steps on detaching the 2015 TFS project collection and backing up the database and moving it over to the other SQL Server and restored it.  I tried to attach the project and now the project collection does not appear in the Attachment list in 2020 DevOps.  Is there a TFS tool command i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

nevermind.  i backed up the sql server database first before i detached the project collection.  I needed to detach and then back up the sql server.  It works now.